# Create as UUID, retrieve as nested instance in generic views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I'm constantly running into this problem. That I'm using a model serializer that needs different fields for creation that for retrieval and I can't seem to find an elegant solution. Here is an example for the way I want to retrieve instances of Book:

```
class BookCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'author',
        )
```

On creation, however, I want to assign an author from a list of existing author by passing the primary key to the serializer. For this, I would need a serializer like this.

```
class BookRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'author', # uses the ID by default
        )
```

So far I've created two serializers and overwrote the `get_serializers()` method of the generic view to select a different serializer if the request type is `GET`. I don't like using so many serializers, though. Also after creation, I'm not able to use the returned instance.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use it as a serializer method field and there, access the request object, check the action and depending on that return either id or the full object.

Comment: Method fields are read-only be default.

Comment: umm. i see, you'll need to override the validators, but that's again not a clean solution

Comment: As Far as I can think of, you need a factory that generates the Serializer on the go

Comment: how about creating dynamic classes? That'd work, I dont know